# Unable to connect: Client network socket disconnected before secure TLS connection was established

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am currently using MongoDB on the web, specifically on cloud.mongodb.com, as I am on a 32-bit system and unable to download MongoDB locally. I'm new to MongoDB, and I tried creating a database just to test how it works. I obtained my connection string and applied it in the VSCode MongoDB extension. However, I encountered the following error:

"Unable to connect: Client network socket disconnected before secure TLS connection was established."

I was expecting it to connect successfully, but it seems there's an issue. Can you please help me resolve this.

Comment: you should at least provide your connection string (with hidden credentials)

Comment: mongodb+srv://efficient0123:<password>@cluster0.wkontum.mongodb.net/
Here.

Comment: How can you have a 32-bit system in 2024? Note, current release of VSCode also exist only for 64-bit. And you may run into problems, because old 32-bit systems do not support latest TLS/SSL versions, the older versions might be disabled by MongoDB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add your `IP address` to `IP Access List` in `Network Access` tab under `Security` Menu of the MongoDB Atlas web menu.

You can give `0.0.0.0/0` this address to allow access from **All IPs**.

If still got error, then check that if your firewall blocks outbound network connections, you must also open outbound access from your application environment to Atlas. You need to configure your firewall to allow your applications to make outbound connections to ports 27015 to 27017 to TCP traffic on Atlas hosts. This grants your applications access to databases stored on Atlas.

[MongoDB Docs link](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/atlas/setup-cluster-security/#add-ip-addresses-to-the-whitelist).

Comment: The error is related to TLS/SSL and not to no connection at all.

Comment: NO WAYYYYYYYYYYYYYY, thanks it worked :)

Comment: @Efficient123 Nice to hear that connection is working now. However your connection string and the error message and the solution provided in this answer does to fit with each other. Most likely you did something else (maybe without noticing it) to make it working. Btw, open just port 27017 should be sufficient. And typically outbound connections are not blocked unless you have very strict security requirements.